# Django Chartit is not displayng yAxis data

Tags: python, django, graph

I am using Django 1.10.3 and python 3.4.2.
For some reason, chartit is not displaying graph line on my chart plot. However, I can see 'data' when I do view-source in my browser. Please point me where I was wrong.

My graph (without graph)

[image: Graph]

Here is what view-source displays

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<div id='cont'><script type="text/javascript">
var _chartit_hco_array = [{"yAxis": [{"title": {"text": "Temp"}}], "series": [{"stacking": false, "data": ["20.83", "20.83", "21.61", "22.11", "23.00", "23.17", "23.94", "24.67", "24.94", "24.94", "25.00", "25.00"], "type": "line", "name": "temperature"}], "xAxis": [{"categories": ["2016-12-16T11:40:13+00:00", "2016-12-16T11:40:13+00:00", "2016-12-16T12:00:32+00:00", "2016-12-16T12:20:51+00:00", "2016-12-16T13:20:56+00:00", "2016-12-16T13:40:22+00:00", "2016-12-16T14:00:41+00:00", "2016-12-16T14:21:00+00:00", "2016-12-16T14:40:26+00:00", "2016-12-16T14:47:29+00:00", "2016-12-16T14:51:02+00:00", "2016-12-16T14:54:34+00:00"], "title": {"text": "Date"}}], "chart": {"renderTo": "cont"}, "title": {"text": "Temp Data of Kedsum"}}];
</script>
<script src="/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js" type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
```

views.py

```
from chartit import DataPool, Chart
from django.shortcuts import render
from monitor.models import LogicLocation, SensorPrologue, SensorThgr122N, SensorKedsum

#def graphs(request):
#  return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'content': ['Graphs Output!!!']})

def graphs(request):
    #Step 1: Create a DataPool with the data we want to retrieve.
    sensordata = DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': SensorKedsum.objects.all()},
              'terms': [
               'date',
                'temperature']}
             ])

    #Step 2: Create the Chart object
    cht = Chart(
            datasource = sensordata,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'line',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'date': [
                     'temperature']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Temp Data of Kedsum'},
               'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Date'}},
               'yAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Temp',
                }}})

    #Step 3: Send the chart object to the template.
    return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'tempchart': cht})
```

graphs.html

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
{% load chartit %}

{% block content %}
            <div id='cont'>{{ tempchart|load_charts:"cont" }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the console output

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 11, 2017 - 20:18:27
Django version 1.10.3, using settings 'smarthome.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[11/Jan/2017 20:18:29] "GET /graphs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1128
[11/Jan/2017 20:18:30] "GET /static/chartit/js/chartloader.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the model field type. In my case it was VARCHAR but it has to be DECIMAL or INTEGER

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Vams,
I see that you are using the latest version of HighCharts.js, which may not be working. The following JavaScript Libraries are required for using Django-Chartit.

- jQuery - versions 1.6.4 and 1.7 are known to work well with django-chartit.
- Highcharts - versions 2.1.7 and 2.2.0 are known to work well with django-chartit.

Try one of the older versions and see if it works. If it does then that means the new versions of HighCharts.js are not compatible with the old ones. If even the older versions don't work that means you have a problem somewhere in your code. I will need a bug open for that to debug further.

--
Alex, maintainer of django-chartit

Comment: Hi Alex,  
thank you for reply but it did not help.
However I have found that the problem is with data representation. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/r0yxkxbt/
It looks like quotations in **data** create the problem. 
I have this `"data": ["20.83", "20.83", "21.61", "22.11", "23.00", "23.17", "23.94", "24.67", "24.94", "24.94", "25.00", "25.00"],`  
     but it works with      
 `data: [20.83, 20.83, 21.61, 22.11, 23.00, 23.17, 23.94, 24.67, 24.94, 24.94, 25.00, 25.00],`